# Why does HTML source from Selenium look different than that shown in a web browser’s view?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am using Python and Selenium to capture the HTML source of a webpage so I can parse it to find a particular element. The source, however, is not the same as what I get when using the “inspect element” view of a browser. The element I am looking for is not in the source Selenium provides. Is there any way to get the same source using Selenium, or using another tool or method?

Comment: In the real web page, JavaScript can modify the DOM so it's different from the original HTML source.

Answer (score 1):

As it is described in the selenium [Documentation](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html#getPageSource--):

> **getPageSource**
>   *java.lang.String getPageSource()*
>
> Get the source of the last loaded page. If the page has been modified after loading (for example, by Javascript) there is no guarantee that the returned text is that of the modified page. Please consult the documentation of the particular driver being used to determine whether the returned text reflects the current state of the page or the text last sent by the web server. The page source returned is a representation of the underlying DOM: do not expect it to be formatted or escaped in the same way as the response sent from the web server. Think of it as an artist's impression.
>
> **Returns:**
>   The source of the current page

Answer (score 0):

You will have to download driver of a web browser that generates this dynamic content. Probably here http://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads 
**from http://chromedriver.chromium.org/getting-started**

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome('/path/to/chromedriver')  # Optional argument, if not specified will search path.
driver.get('http://www.google.com/xhtml');
time.sleep(5) # Let the user actually see something!
search_box = driver.find_element_by_name('q')
search_box.send_keys('ChromeDriver')
search_box.submit()
time.sleep(5) # Let the user actually see something!
driver.quit()
```

this will popup a Chrome window, work and get the content. Don't forget to close it after and set **time.sleep()** so the driver has some time to generate the content. You can also run it **headless**, then you run it in a virtual window and can set f.e. window width and height 4000px, normal mode doesnt allow that

Comment: what does this have to do with the question asked?

Comment: @CoreyGoldberg it's not seen in source code because it's dynamic content, therefore you have to generate the content first in order to see it?

Comment: did you read the answer you provided?  it's just instructions for getting started.

Comment: @CoreyGoldberg no I typed that with my feet and blindfold.. I had the same question some weeks ago, such answer helped me to solve my problem. Once I first try to help someone that has the same problem as I did some egoistic entity walks from to top to criticise any try for help? I think that there was something about such unwelcoming behaviour in StackOverflow's annual report

Comment: StackOverflow is for asking specific programming questions and answering what was asked.  Your answer doesn't answer the question whatsoever.  That's just a fact.  You should simply improve or remove your answer rather than venting about how welcome it makes you feel.

Comment: @CoreyGoldberg on your profile under your name is written human